ATAN2 in Excel doesn't work with references
I tried to convert a pair of columns for x-values and y-values into two columns for radii and angles.
For the radii I could write =SQRT($x^2 + $x^2), but for =ATAN2($x,$y) I get complaints about invalid signs in the formula.
I have also tried =ATAN($y/$x); that works, so the number of arguments seems to make the difference but doesn't explain the reason for the difference.
So besides an explanation for that quirk I would appreciate suggestions for solutions or workarounds.
So here is a screenshot of the issue; hope it helps.

Edit:
A workaround is =ATAN($y/$x)+($x<0)*(PI()*(($y>=0)-($y<0)))
Explanation: comparison evaluate to numeric values 0 or 1, which allows one to combine conditons into numerical expression and thus implement the piecewise formula for Atan2 in a single formula

What is the Excel error you get and what are the input values that throw the error?

What is $x? That token is not a valid name nor a valid range reference.  What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Wrong answer? Error message? Excel crash? Computer crash? Something else?  Where is your sample data set that can be used to reproduce your problem?

@RonRosenfeld $x is just the content of some cell say $A1; it doesn't matter which cell's content it is. "Doesn't work means that Excel doesn't accept e.g. =ATAN2($A1,$A2); it doesn't accept the dollar signs. Why don't you just try yourself to calculate e.g. =ATAN2($A1,$A2) with a 1 in the two cells $A1 and $A2 and see what happens

@ManfredWeis =ATAN2($A1,$A2) => 0.785398163  And I'm not aware of an Excel error message ("does not accept dollar signs"). Why are you reluctant to share the exact wording of the error message?

@ManfredWeis Could it be that your actual error message starts with "There's a problem with this formula"? If so, one explanation would be that your system uses semicolons and not commas as argument separators.

@RonRosenfeld you are right, the comma instead of a semicolon is the issue on my system. I really start loving locales.

@ManfredWeis Glad you got it sorted. For future reference, note that had you provided information about your actual error code in your initial post, this would have been answered much sooner.
